# Should we start using SHA-3?

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is SHA-3 and why did we change it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21112/what-is-sha-3-and-why-did-we-change-it)

[SHA-3 has been finalized!](http://www.nist.gov/itl/csd/sha-100212.cfm) So, what does secuirty.se think about the new hash funciton?  Should we start replacing all uses of md5/sha1/sha2 with Keccak?   Is it too soon?  Or do you think that the NIST process is rigorous enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there is no "real SHA-3" yet. In a few months, NIST will publish a specification which will *define* unambiguously what SHA-3 is. Unless there is a big blunder somewhere, we can *predict* that SHA-3 will be bit-to-bit compatible with the specification of Keccak as submitted for round 3 of the competition.

Then there is no reason to replace SHA-2 with (future-)SHA-3: neither scientifically (SHA-2 is not broken, far from it; and, for performance, Keccak is not terribly better than SHA-2, and often worse, depending on the architecture), nor administratively (the NIST people themselves posit that there is no need to replace SHA-2 with SHA-3).

There *are* reasons to replace MD5 and SHA-1 with SHA-2 (or SHA-3 in the future) but these reasons were already valid last week and you should already be doing it.

*Algorithm agility* is an important quality of **protocols** -- but that's a question of protocol design. People who are qualified to design security protocols already know it, and the other should refrain from designing protocols.

Answer (score 2):

Hash functions are fairly new, and we are still discovering new cryptanalysis attacks against them. SHA-3 looks useful, so I disagree with [Schneier's comments about a no-award](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/09/sha-3_will_be_a.html).  However, we should plan on having a SHA-4 competition in the near future.  Being able to change what hash function that you rely upon is a useful feature.  SSL/TLS is a good example of this.